# java - String to Date Format

Tags: java, string, date

I have a problem with `String` conversion to `Date` Format. Please help me. Below is my code:

```
String strDate = "23/05/2012"; // Here the format of date is MM/dd/yyyy
```

Now i want to convert the above String to Date Format like "***23 May, 2012***".

I am using below code but i am getting value as "***Wed May 23 00:00:00 BOT 2012***"

```
String string = "23/05/2012";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Wed May 23 00:00:00 BOT 2012
```

How can i get the value as "***23 May, 2012***". Please help me friends....

Comment: Just use another `SimpleDateFormat` and see @UwePlonus' answer. Also, beware in case this matters to you: `SimpleDateFormat` _is not thread safe_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method `format()` from the class `SimpleDateFormat` with the correct pattern.

Simple use:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Answer (score 4):

You must render the date again.

You have the string and you parse it correctly back to a `Date` object. Now, you have to render that `Date` object the way you want.

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` again, changing the pattern.
Your code should then look like

```
String string = "23/05/2012";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
String newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy").format(date);
System.out.println(newFormat); // 23 May, 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        String strDate = "23/02/2012";
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strDate);
        String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy").format(date);
        System.out.println(date1);
    }
}
```